# How is it possible to get the "isContextOnly" tag from Microsoft QnA Maker for multi-turn dialogues with C#?

Tags: c#, azure-qna-maker

In JSON the tag "isContextOnly" is present (found in [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/qnamaker/how-to/multiturn-conversation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/qnamaker/how-to/multiturn-conversation#a-json-response-to-return-an-initial-answer-and-follow-up-prompts))

But with c# using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs there is no way to get for example response.Answers[0].isContextOnly

[image: QnA-Maker]

Is there any solution?

Answer (score 0):

One of the samples in the Microsoft Botframework dotnet samples repo, [#49.QnABot-All-Features](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/49.qnamaker-all-features), is designed to handle the different features offered by QnA maker, including active learning and context-only. More specifically, the dialog class in the sample `QnAMakerBaseDialog`, inherits from `QnAMakerDialog`.

In the parent `QnAMakerDialog`, there's a method that checks for multi-turn context:

```
private async Task<DialogTurnResult> CheckForMultiTurnPromptAsync(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var dialogOptions = ObjectPath.GetPathValue<QnAMakerDialogOptions>(stepContext.ActiveDialog.State, Options);
    if (stepContext.Result is List<QueryResult> response && response.Count > 0)
    {
        // -Check if context is present and prompt exists 
        // -If yes: Add reverse index of prompt display name and its corresponding QnA ID
        // -Set PreviousQnAId as answer.Id
        // -Display card for the prompt
        // -Wait for the reply
        // -If no: Skip to next step

        var answer = response.First();

        if (answer.Context != null && answer.Context.Prompts.Count() > 0)
        {
            var previousContextData = ObjectPath.GetPathValue(stepContext.ActiveDialog.State, QnAContextData, new Dictionary<string, int>());

            foreach (var prompt in answer.Context.Prompts)
            {
                previousContextData[prompt.DisplayText] = prompt.QnaId;
            }

            ObjectPath.SetPathValue(stepContext.ActiveDialog.State, QnAContextData, previousContextData);
            ObjectPath.SetPathValue(stepContext.ActiveDialog.State, PreviousQnAId, answer.Id);
            ObjectPath.SetPathValue(stepContext.ActiveDialog.State, Options, dialogOptions);

            // Get multi-turn prompts card activity.
            var message = QnACardBuilder.GetQnADefaultResponse(answer, dialogOptions.ResponseOptions.DisplayPreciseAnswerOnly);
            await stepContext.Context.SendActivityAsync(message, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);

            return new DialogTurnResult(DialogTurnStatus.Waiting);
        }
    }

    return await stepContext.NextAsync(stepContext.Result, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

This is part of the internal waterfall of getting a QnA answer from QnAMaker.ai. It does look for a context in `if (answers.Context != null ...`.

[image: QnAResponseContext QueryResult.Context definition hover image]

In QueryResult.cs, Context is defined as:

```
/// <summary>
/// Gets or sets context for multi-turn responses.
/// </summary>
/// <value>
/// The context from which the QnA was extracted.
/// </value>
[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "context")]
public QnAResponseContext Context { get; set; }
```

So to  answer  your question, to get the isContextOnly tag results in C#, debug into the results from a QnAMaker query, and you'll find a attribute called `Context`. This is what you're  looking for.

Comment: Thank you @JJ_Wailes. I tried to test your example. Unfortunately, it comes to an error because "Options" was not found. Please tell me all required using directives.

Comment: The errors are: 
CS0103: The Name "Options" does not exist in the current context (Line 3 in your example)
CS0103: The Name "PreviousQnAId" does not exist in the current context (Line 25 in your example)
CS0103: The Name "Options" does not exist in the current context (Line 27 in your example)
CS0117: "QnACardBuilder" does not contain a definition for "GetQnADefaultResponse" (Line 30 in your example)

Comment: And CS1061: "DisplayPreciseAnswerOnly" does not contain a definition for "DisplayPreciseAnswerOnly" and no accessible extension method accepting a first argument of type "QnADialogResponseOptions" could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) (Line 30 in your example)